# Deducting Stock

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors

I have a `JTable` which acts as an order pane. When I complete an order and click a `JButton` called "New Order" it clears the `JTable` and it also clears the order specifics such as price and change etc. What I am trying to do when I click the "New Order" `JButton` is to deduct the stock that was sold in the last order before it was cleared.

I have a table in my SQL database with products which have columns called:

`ProductID (PK), ProductName, ProductDescrp, Type, SupplierName, Quantity, Price`

My goal in all of this is to reduce the `Quantity` in stock in the database on any product that has been sold in an order. This is my code so far.

```
jbtNewOrder.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                    if(e.getSource().equals(jbtNewOrder)) 
            {
                total = 0.0;
                totalTF.setText("");
                tenderedTF.setText("");
                changeTF.setText("");
                model.setRowCount(0);

            try
            {
                int prodID = 0;
                String sql = ("UPDATE product " + "SET Quantity = Quantity -1" + (getDBQuantity(prodID)-1) + " WHERE ProductID = " + prodID);
                databaseUpdate(sql);
            }
            catch(Exception e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
              return status;
           }

        // return quantity of a product in DB
            public int getDBQuantity(int prodID)
            {
                int quantity=0;
                try
                {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);

                statement = (Statement) conn.createStatement();
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select Quantity from team_project.product WHERE ProductID = " + prodID);

                while (resultSet.next())
                {       
                    quantity = (resultSet.getInt("Quantity"));
                }
                conn.close();
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return quantity;
                }}


     private int databaseUpdate(String sqlUpdate)
       {
          int status = 0;

          try{
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
             statement = conn.createStatement();
             status = statement.executeUpdate(sqlUpdate);
             conn.close(); 
          }       

          catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }   
          return status;
       }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing.

Comment: Do you even *glance* at the preview of the question formatting before saving the changes? Also note that is not an MCVE / SSCCE, so voting to close.

Comment: I get this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 Syntax error on token ")", ; expected. And yes i tried to fix the trailing bracket

Comment: The code is not complete. There are bits missing and so it is not really possible to see what you are trying to do. Download Eclipse or some other IDE, make all the red crosses go away. Then try asking again.

Comment: OK.. it's now looking better, but no MCVE / SSCCE & the error information should be part of the question. On the subject of the error, don't try running code that does not compile cleanly! Fix the compilation error first.

Comment: ive updated my code

Comment: I have updated my code as shown above. It does now compile but it just does not do anything. It doesn't update quantities on Button Click

Comment: Can anyone help me.

Comment: *"ive updated my code"* 1) But you've apparently either not read, or not understood the documents I linked in my first comment. The uncompilabe code snippet above is not either an MCVE or an SSCCE. 2) Tip: Add @GreenCoder (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 3) As for me, I have better things to do than offer tips to people that don't listen, so I'm out of here. Good luck with it.

Comment: Hey man Im only a beginner. I cant give you a MCVE as my program is 1500 lines long @Andrew Thompson

Comment: The idea of creating an MCVE / SSCCE is to remove the unnecessary parts of the program until it is a concise, self contained code that shows the problem. The process of doing so takes effort on your part, but is well worth it, given you often discover the problem while making it. If not, at least it provides a short, to the point example for others to find the error. If you could not be bothered creating an MCVE / SSCCE.. 1) It is likely we cannot find the problem, which is often in code not shown. 2) Why should anyone else bother trying to help?

Comment: Listen man, forget it.